# Convert location units from miles to meters Android

Tags: java, android, gps, location, metrics

i want to convert miles to meters? and other units to metric?
I tried many variants to change values but its didn't help me,please someone can do it? if it's neccessary i can share all my code, and yes sorry for my English.

There is my code please help.

```
Double speedInMilesPerHour = location.getSpeed()* 3.6; //inMeters
    requestParams.put("speed",  Integer.toString(speedInMilesPerHour.intValue()));

    try {
        requestParams.put("date", URLEncoder.encode(dateFormat.format(date), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}

    requestParams.put("locationmethod", location.getProvider());

    if (totalDistanceInMeters > 0) {
        requestParams.put("distance", String.format("%.1f", totalDistanceInMeters / 1609)); // in miles,
    } else {
        requestParams.put("distance", "0.0"); // in miles
    }

    requestParams.put("username", sharedPreferences.getString("userName", ""));
    requestParams.put("phonenumber", sharedPreferences.getString("appID", "")); // uuid
    requestParams.put("sessionid", sharedPreferences.getString("sessionID", "")); // uuid

    Double accuracyInFeet = location.getAccuracy()* 3.28;
    requestParams.put("accuracy",  Integer.toString(accuracyInFeet.intValue()));

    Double altitudeInFeet = location.getAltitude() * 3.28;
    requestParams.put("extrainfo",  Integer.toString(altitudeInFeet.intValue()));
```

Comment: Just google it `miles to meter`.

Comment: but how for example Double accuracyInFeet = location.getAccuracy()* 3.28; this i can convert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just write simple conversion methods that work with doubles:

```
    public static final double METERS_IN_MILE = 1609.344;

    public static double metersToMiles(double meters) {
        return meters / METERS_IN_MILE;
    }
    
    public static double milesToMeters(double miles) {
        return miles * METERS_IN_MILE;
    }
```

Comment: Error in `milesToMeters` formula. Should be `miles / 0.0006213711`

Comment: As far as I can tell 1 mile = 1609.344 meters. I'm not sure where your 1609.3440057765 comes from?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile#:%7E:text=An%20international%20mile%20%3D%201609.344%20%2F%20(,mile%20of%20exactly%201%2C609.344%20metres